# VBA Excel Look for values between 2 dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba

For each cell in 'myRange' I want to check for a range of values in Sheet2 and if the values in Sheet2 are found in myRange then for the corresponding row I want to put the value from Column A into Column E

As it stands, I'm only able to look for a single value from Sheet2 ("A1"). When attempting to extend this range I get errors.

Is there a way to make the range in Sheet2 dynamic, please?

```
Sub Find_values()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim LR As Long

    LR = Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myRange = Sheets(1).Range("B1:B" & LR)

    For Each Cell In myRange

    If Cell.Value = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value Then Cell.Offset(0, 3) = Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value


    Next Cell

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use **nested loops** or the *Find* method.

Comment: Show us some sample data

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz, Hi Ricardo, I've updated with some screenshots

Comment: @Gary's Student, Hello good Sir, excuse my ignorance, but I think the nested loops would mean me repeating the For Each Loop for every cell in Column A on Sheet2 ? If that's the case I'll need to update my code every time I add a new entry to Column A Sheet2 (which i'll be doing often) and this would get cumbersome hence the need for a dynamic range

Comment: @Itachi_Uchiha Please be more specific with how Sheet2 values relate to Sheet1 values and where do you want to put the result. As per my understanding, In sheet 2 you would like to put in cell E1: XR0407?

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz, thanks for your time Ricardo, please see the 3rd screenshot of what i'm trying to achieve. So here as an example Sheet2 cell A1 has the value/string 'CA4028 CA5104 CA6195 176354'; every time this value is found on Sheet1 I want it to return the 'Scale' on the same Row in Column E. The code works fine when only looking at one cell (cell A1 Sheet2), but I want it to also look for A2, A3, A4 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggested, you can simply nest two For Each loops.

```
Sub Find_values()

    Dim myRange1 As Range
    Dim myRange2 As Range
    Dim Cell1 As Range
    Dim Cell2 as Range

    Set myRange1 = Sheets(1).Range(range("B1"),range("B1").end(xlDown))
    Set myRange2 = Sheets(2).Range(range("A1"),range("A1").end(xlDown)) 'This range is also dynamic and will adapt to teh number of entries you ahve in Sheet2

    For Each Cell1 In myRange1
    For Each Cell2 In myRange2

    If Cell1.Value2 = Cell2.Value2 Then
        Cell1.Offset(0, 3) = Cell1.Offset(0, -1).Value2
        Exit for 'Save you some useless processing time since the entry has already been found
    end If

    Next Cell2
    Next Cell1

End Sub
```

Note I have re-wrote your Range statment to be more cleaner.
Note I have also changed your .value statement into .value2, which depending on the type of data used in your cell will in some cases work better.

Comment: dude thank you so much that worked. However it did give me an 'object-defined error' at the Set myRange1 line, so i modified both myRange1 and myRange2 to match my original range syntax. Taking nothing away from your code though, just putting this out there for anyone else who uses your code.

Comment: Pleasure to be of help! Try Set myRange1 = Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).range("B1"),Sheets(1).range("B1").end(xlDown))

Comment: Thumbs up, that works and looks a lot neater than my range syntax!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

Convert the data in Sheet1 to an structured Excel table:

1- Select the range from scale's cell to the concatenate last cell

2- Click on the Ribbon "Home" | "Styles" | "Format as table" |

3- Check "My table has headers" box (mark it)

4- Write down the name of the table (While selecting one cell inside the table, look in the "Table tools" ribbon | "Table name"

5- Repeat the previous steps for the data in Sheet2

6- Add the following code to a VBA module:

```
Sub LookupValues()

    ' Define object variables
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceTable As ListObject
    Dim sourceCell As Range

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataTable As ListObject



    ' Define other variables
    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    Dim sourceTableName As String

    Dim dataSheetName As String
    Dim dataTableName As String


    ' >>>>Customize this<<<<<
    sourceSheetName = "Sheet2"
    sourceTableName = "Table2"
    dataSheetName = "Sheet1"
    dataTableName = "Table1"

    ' Initialize worksheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sourceSheetName)
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dataSheetName)

    ' Initialize source table
    Set sourceTable = sourceSheet.ListObjects(sourceTableName)
    Set dataTable = dataSheet.ListObjects(dataTableName)

    ' Loop through every cell in sourceSheet
    For Each sourceCell In sourceTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells
        ' >>>>Customize this<<<<<
        ' In the following code:
        ' Offset(0, 4) -> 4 stand for 4 columns after column A
        ' Index(dataTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1) -> 1 stands to return the first column of the data table
        ' Match(sourceCell.Value, dataTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2) -> 2 stands to look in the second column of the data table
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(sourceCell.Value, dataTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), 0)) Then
            sourceCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.Index(dataTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), Application.Match(sourceCell.Value, dataTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), 0))
        End If

    Next sourceCell


End Sub
```

6- Customize the code to fit your needs

7- Test it and let us know if it works
Hope it helps!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your time and patience. Please see the 4th screenshot which is the result i get after executing your code. The problem is this is acting like a vlookup, returning a single scale and returning the results to Sheet2 but i need the results to go on Sheet1. If you look at screenshot 3 the value/string 'CA4028 CA5104 CA6195 176354' has multiple scales returned in Column E on Sheet1 when i execute my code. I can understand why you would think the results (scales) would go on Sheet2 because the scales are already there on Sheet1

Comment: I want to return all the scales for every concatenate onto Sheet1 if that concatenate is found in Sheet2. I've tried to modify your code so it reverses to put the results onto Sheet1 but haven't yet succeeded. Nonetheless, the code you've given is very helpful in developing my understanding as i'm new to VBA (and will probably always be new!)

Comment: @Itachi_Uchiha So if the concatenate value exists in sheet2 you want to put the code in column e in sheet 1?

Comment: yup Ricardo. But my problem is now solved (please see Ama's answer above). Want to thank you immensely for all your time though. Much respect to you Sir